# How to replace Null fields with 0s

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-expression

I have a field in a `matrix` that has some nulls.  I would like to replace all the `null`s with `0`s.  This is the expression I currently have in the field:

```
=Sum(IIf(Code.isVM(Fields!deviceType.Value), 0, 1))
```

I'm guessing I have to have an `IsNothing` expression in there but I can't figure out how to add this with this existing `expression`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
=Iif(
   Sum(IIf(Code.isVM(Fields!deviceType.Value), 0, 1)) Is Nothing, 
   0, 
   Sum(IIf(Code.isVM(Fields!deviceType.Value), 0, 1))
)
```

Comment: Thanks both for the response!  Nathan yours worked perfectly for what I was looking for.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I recall testing for length greater than 0 worked well.

```
=IIf(Len(Fields!deviceType.Value) > 0, Fields!deviceType.Value, 0)
```